# Add specific close reason and explicit point in the help pages for learning material requests

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, help-center

Prelude:

[How do we feel about requests for learning materials?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/how-do-we-feel-about-requests-for-learning-materials)

I'm tagging this as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) since there was already previous discussion about the topic, but recent events may need further discussion.

The proposal is composed of two changes:

1. Explicitly add in the help center, on/off topic help pages and tour that we don't like learning material requests.
2. Add an off-topic reason that specifically address this issue (exact wording could be found in SU/Programers and other SE sites, so we could just copy them).

Do you see the worth in this change? It's necessary? Do you have another idea?

Comment: Yes! Please! I feel the most important thing is to specify this on the help pages since we can't expect new users to be aware of the close reasons. Having a dedicated close reason would be great as well, but the help should come first.

Comment: I'd like something like this in almost all sites I frequent here..

Answer (score 4):

Why should we have a specific close reason for this?

Ok, [that's the suggestion on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186530/what-close-reason-for-polling-questions). But I disagree, because this is not a site-specific policy, it's a general thing everywhere on Stack Exchange that tutorial requests don't work.

While none of the built-in close reasons are a perfect fit, I go with “too broad” or “primarily opinion-based” with an explanatory comment.

There is already a help center page: “[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)”

> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
>
> (…)
>
> Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
>
> (…)

Comment: Maybe that question should be re-asked but with a "feature request" in MSO, since you got a MSO answer.

Comment: The point is that requests for learning materials are not explicitly off topic in the help pages. New users cannot be expected to know this and this ignorance can lead to tensions. Stating that such questions are off topic would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence has now been added to the [on-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page. I don't think a specific close reason is needed, too broad should serve fine.

> Please note that requests for [learning materials](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2642/) (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications).

Comment: That wording looks weird. Instead of not isn't "note"

Comment: @Braiam Argh! You're absolutely right. That was a typo of course. Luckily, slm has already fixed it. Thanks.