# How should we word the off-topic reason for learning material?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Background: [Add specific close reason and explicit point in the help pages for learning material requests](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/add-specific-close-reason-and-explicit-point-in-the-help-pages-for-learning-mate)

I think that I made a mistake with my earlier proposal, since I didn't included proof of concept about neither the off-topic reason (I agree with Gilles that there should be a site wide reason...) nor the help page. This is focused in the off-topic reason.

Any other idea?

Comment: Do we want to mention the software recommendations site?

Comment: @derobert Soft Recs is strongly against it until they get out of beta.

Comment: Are we looking to add this as a specific close reason? I though Gilles A in your previous Q was spot on. Requests asking for learning material and tutorials is off-topic.

Comment: Rather than adding a close reason, I'd be for adding this to our help docs.

Answer (score 6):

In the end I went with

> Please note that requests for [learning materials](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2642/) (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications).

The text above has been added to the [on-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page. I don't think a specific close reason is needed, too broad should serve fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking in something like:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Unix & Linux as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem you are currently facing and what has been done so far to solve it.